# dragging multiple list items simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two lists connected with jQuery UI's `sortable`, allowing to drag items from one list to another.

http://jsbin.com/uraga3

Is there a simple way to drag several items at the same time - e.g. to move items #3, #4 and #7 from left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the plugin.

You can write some custom code to add items to a selection and then move multiple at once.

Like:

```
$( "li" ).bind( "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('sorting-selected');
});

$( "ul" ).bind( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
  $('li.sorting-selected').appendTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, and I like the simplicity of it. I might look into adding a helper clone for visual feedback, perhaps based on fudgey's post.

I wish I could accept both your answers - will choose one once I've figured out my final solution.